# Unexpected behaviour of ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

The following is snippet from code that I've written:

```cpp
int n,i,j;
map<int,int>mp;
vector<int>vec;
cin>>n;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin>>j;
    mp[j]==0? mp[j]=1,vec.push_back(j): mp[j]=1;
}
```

For the second line inside `for` loop, CodeBlocks-16.01 version shows the following error:

```
second operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
```

But when I change the line to:

```cpp
mp[j]==0? vec.push_back(j), mp[j]=1: mp[j]=1;
```

There is no error. What is the issue with following line?

```cpp
mp[j]==0? mp[j]=1,vec.push_back(j): mp[j]=1;
```

Comment: Thank you Kashinath Patekar for reviewing my post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not just `if (mp[j] == 0) {vec.push_back(j);}; mp[j] = 1;`?

Comment: You're welcome @emdadul_islam. Consider marking answer as accepted if it solves the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Or `if(mp.insert({j, 1}).second) { vec.push_back(j); }`?

Comment: @Andras Deak, yeah I can use "if condition" instead of the  ternary operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand the error, let's take a look the operands to the conditional operator.

**The second operand:**

```cpp
mp[j]=1, vec.push_back(j)
```

The operand is two expressions separated by the `comma operator`.
The way the comma operator works here is that it evaluates `mp[j]=1` which results in value `1`, it discards the value and evaluates the next expression `vec.push_back(j)` which returns `void`.

Hence the *final value* of whole **second operand** is of type `void` (This is what the error says).

**The third operand:**

```cpp
mp[j]=1
```

This expression evaluates to `1`, which is of type `int`. (Thus it is not `void` or `thrown-exception`, and that is what the error says).

**When you change the second operand:**
In the expression

```cpp
vec.push_back(j), mp[j]=1
```

`vec.push_back(j)` evaluates to `void`, this value is discarded and then `mp[j]=1` evaluates to `1` which is type `int`. Now both operands are `int`, hence no error.